# NSRangeException in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hello every one i am new in swift, i am facing an issue in my program. i have save some data in '**let defaultStudentId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()**' but every time the application get stopped. **defaultStudentId.objectForKey("studentId")** this "studentId" is coming from another ViewController.... i need help
here is my code and the error.....

```
import UIKit

class OTPViewController: ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var OTP_code: UITextField!
    let defaultStudentId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func confirm(sender: AnyObject) {

        let std_id = defaultStudentId.objectForKey("studentId")
        let sendOTPCode = "StudentId=\(std_id)&CODE=\(self.OTP_code.text)&PartnerID=4B67B239CF3735814C063DB89D750481"
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://serviceforonair.examonair.com/AndroidService.asmx/VerifyOTPAndActivateStudent")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPBody = sendOTPCode.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print(error)
                return
            }
            do{
                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                var message : String!
                message = responseString?.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 76), withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</string>", withString: "")
                print(self.defaultStudentId)

            }
            catch let jsonException{
                print(jsonException)
            }
        }
        task.resume()



    }
}
```

Error
2016-08-15 20:14:10.555 DBMCI[21415:143621] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dcedd85 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110159deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dcedcbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dcb90ad mutateError + 221
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010e7c887c -[NSString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:] + 142
    5   DBMCI                               0x000000010d62de96 _TFFC5DBMCI17OTPViewController7confirmFPs9AnyObject_T_U_FTGSqCSo6NSData_GSqCSo13NSURLResponse_GSqCSo7NSError__T_ + 902
    6   DBMCI                               0x000000010d622c87 _TTRXFo_oGSqCSo6NSData_oGSqCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSqCSo7NSError__dT__XFdCb_dGSqS__dGSqS0__dGSqS1___dT** + 103
    7   CFNetwork                           0x0000000111118b49 **75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
    8   CFNetwork                           0x000000011112b0f2 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 302
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010e82f630 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010e76a805 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010e74d725 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 646
    12  Foundation                          0x000000010e74d336 __NSOQSchedule_f + 194
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011197a3eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011196082c _dispatch_queue_drain + 2215
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011195fd4d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 601
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111962996 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1420
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111962405 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000111cb74de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000111cb5341 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

Basically

```
let std_id = defaultStudentId.objectForKey("studentId")
```

returns an optional value, so in a String Interpolation `"StudentId=\(std_id)"`you will get for example `"StudentId=Optional(24)"` instead of the expected `"StudentId=24"` which is certainly not what you want.

Assuming the object for key `studentId` is a `String` replace the line above with

```
guard let std_id = defaultStudentId.stringForKey("studentId") else { return }
```

It checks if the value for key exists and unwraps the optional value on success otherwise it exits the method.

The error message of the crash is related to the line

```
message = responseString?.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 76), withString: "").stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</string>", withString: "")
```

Avoid to hard code the range length, calculate it. If you can't, check the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your responseString maybe an empty string just (""). So when you try to replace using an range the app crashes. Have a look at responseString's value, check if the character length is greater than 0 and 76.

Add this **print(responseString?.characters.count**, "responseString's character length") after the var message: String declaration.